# How to create offline payment method like PurchaseOrder, COD etc

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, magento2.3.1, payment-gateway

Trying to create a simple offline payment method in Magento 2.3. After Magento 2.2, the abstract class

> \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod

has been deprecated, so I can't use it. Also, I am not connecting to the payment gateway. So, I am not sure whether to create Facade/Adapter for the same. Anyone can please help me on that ?

Comment: https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/2361-2/

Comment: The abstract class \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod has been deprecated. The tutorial says about extending the abstract class.

Comment: Then please look into into core files. How they have accomplish this.

Comment: They have extended the same abstract class, but still we can't use the deprecated class, right ?

Comment: Using it won't cause any issue as magento guys are using same. But, keep in touch with code when they start using any other class then you can change.

Comment: I did all the research but didn't find anything working, so I am going with extension of deprecated class, in Magento 2.3.2 also, they have used the same. Will keep an eye for the same once magento changes it.

Thanks @mighty_hk for the help.

Comment: welcome brother, Happy coding !:)

Comment: Hi @mighty_hk I am not able to set the order status to Processing for my payment method. Can you please suggest something in this ? I have already set the config.xml file. Also Model file related to the status is not affecting the status.

Comment: As your custom payment method is offline, so you need to generate invoice in order to set status to processing.

Comment: Okay Thanks for the help.